# Automatically checking argument types in commands of a Telegram bot

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram

I am writing a simple Telegram bot in Python 3 using the `python-telegram-bot` library. A `command` is a Telegram message that looks like this: `/command_name arg1 arg2 arg3...`. The bot should handle the users' messages by changing its internal state and making responses to the users.

I was not very happy with the 'command handling' provided by the library because this code is not beautiful at all and is very noisy:

```py
def caps(update, context):
    text_caps = ' '.join(context.args).upper()
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, text=text_caps)

caps_handler = CommandHandler('caps', caps)
dispatcher.add_handler(caps_handler)
```

So I wanted to create a more convenient way, and now a command looks like this:

```py
@cmd('hello')
def cmd_hello(msg, a:int, b:[float], c:str):
    s = ''
    s += 'Number: '+str(a)+'\n'
    s += 'Floats: '+str(b)+'\n'
    s += 'String: '+c
    return s
```

If i send this command: `/hello 1 3.14 5 3.7 world` to the bot, the response will be:

```
Number: 1
Floats: [3.14, 5.0, 3.7]
String: world
```

I am using the `inspect` module to read the argument annotations of a function and store them in a `dict`:

```py
Cmd = namedtuple('Cmd',['func','patterns'])
commands = dict()

def cmd(name):
    def deco(func):
        args = []
        sig = signature(func)

        for arg_name, param in sig.parameters.items():
            ann = param.annotation
            if ann:
                args.append(ann)
            else:
                args.append(str)

        args.pop(0)
        commands[name] = Cmd(func, tuple(args))
        return func
    return deco
```

The `process_args` function takes: 1) a list of raw (`str`) arguments that a bot receives in a message, 2) a list of patterns to match the arguments; and returns a list of processed (converted) arguments or raises `CmdError` if the arguments are incorrect.

```py
def process_args(args, patterns):
    patterns = list(patterns)

    processed = []
    while patterns:
        if not args:
            raise CmdError("Not enough arguments")

        pattern = patterns.pop(0)

        if pattern in (int, float, str):
            arg = args[0]
            try:
                converted = pattern(arg)
            except Exception:
                raise CmdError(f"Cannot parse argument {arg} as {pattern.__name__}")
            args.pop(0)
            processed.append(converted)

        elif isinstance(pattern, list):
            pat_single = pattern[0]
            collected = []

            match = True
            while match:
                try:
                    x = process_args([args[0]], [pat_single])[0]
                except CmdError: # If the pattern isn't matched anymore
                    match = False
                else:
                    collected.append(x)
                    args.pop(0)
            processed.append(collected)

    return processed
```

This function looks really bad. Is there a better way of implementing a pattern matching like this?

Comment: Hi, I don't have much time to skim through the code right now, but I think you may find [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50563546/5069029) of some interest. There is also [this answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/195494/84718) that have some pre-thoughts to the one I posted on SO.

Comment: @MathiasEttinger Hi. I'm not trying to validate the type of the function arguments. I am parsing a user input according to a list of patterns.